# Triggering a fake select dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm working on a Chrome extension, and part of the spec is filling in forms. Unfortunately forms like https://accounts.google.com/SignUp don't use real select boxes.

Is there a good way of interacting with these type of select boxes from Javascript?

Comment: In the end, only the actual form inputs are going to matter anyway.  You can set their values, which should be sufficient depending on if the result needs to be visible to the user.

Comment: Yep, it already does that. Unfortunately it will matter to the user that they can't see the change.